# How would I return the Date 4 days ago in a complex format

Tags: php

How can I get the full date 4 days ago:

```
$today = new DateTime('4 days ago');
```

To be printed in the following format:

```
"Monday 10th of August 2016"
```

Comment: Searching the web with your title reveals several answers. Did you try that?

Comment: @Chris: while I agree, this question doesn't show any evidence of even the slightest bit of research on the OP's part, the particular format string isn't obviously documented (as in: how to escape `t`, `h` and `f`. With a bit of research, this question would've probably been posted as: how can I escape character literals in my date format or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried anything yet? PHP has an excellent [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) component that can basically do all you want and more. The output formatting options are pretty extensive, too, and you can use the same format strings to parse date strings:

```
$date = new DateTime($inString);//or DateTime::createFromFormat for more exotic formats
$interval = new \DateInterval('P4D');//4 days
$interval->invert = 1;// negative 4 days now
$result = $date->add($interval);//subtract 4 days
echo $result->format('Y-m-d');
```

The format options are [extensively documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

### Basic [demo](https://eval.in/622697)

If you want to get today minus some number of days, you can even write something as simple, and readable as this:

```
$date = new \DateTime('4 days ago');
echo $date->format('l d\t\h \of F Y'); // ok, so this is what you wanted
```

It couldn't be easier, all you need to do is read the manual...
Your format string can contain words, or any other character (like `/` or `-`) that will be used as literal characters in your result. If the format string contains character literals that are interpreted as format specifiers (like in your case, `th` and `o`), just use a backslash to escape them and they'll be printed out as string literals.

In short RTM

Comment: Thank you everyone for being patient and posting.

I did a search but am new to PHP from Javascript and couldnt figure out the format part of the function. Thanks once again :)

Comment: @AliC: Please read the help section. You're asked not to leave _"thank you"_ comments, but rather mark the helpful answers by upvoting and/or accepting the answer. Acceprting an answer is done by clicking that hollow V-shaped icon to the left of the answer in question. Upvoting can be done by clicking the grey arrow on top of the answers' score.

Answer (score 0):

try to search before asking :)

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-5 days'));
```

Comment: The format the OP is after isn't `Y-m-d`, it's `'l d\t\h \of F Y'` While your code works, it might be useful to add links to relevant documentation, too